# Catching Exceptions and Rethrowing

Tags: java, exception, throw

I'm new to the Java scene but currently working on an assigned assessment. I'm wondering if there is a way to catch an exception inside a class function and throw another exception so the function that called the class function doesn't need to know about the first exception thrown.

For example

```
public void foo() throws MasterException {
    try {
        int a = bar();
    } catch (MasterException e) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public void bar() throws MasterException, MinorException {
    try {
        int a = 1;
    } catch (MinorException e) {
        throw new MasterException();
    }
}
```

I hope this example explains what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I want the calling function not to know about `MinorException`.

Comment: Other than that you've kept `throws MinorException` on `bar()`, this seems like you've already done exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: There's no need to list MinorException in bar`s `throws` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `, MinorException` from the declaration of `bar` and you are done.
I would also do:

```
throw new MasterException(e);
```

If `MasterException` had a constructor that supported it (its standard it does, the `Exception` class do).

Comment: Thanks mate, I come from a c/c++ background and never really used exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions is a blessing and a curse, imho mostly a curse (when they are checked). Grasping this concept of re-throwing them looks like a good step of "mastering" them.

Comment: Yea I was always lead to believe they were a curse in C++.

Comment: @esej: Can you please explain why grasping and re throwing is a good thing? I hope I am not hijacking the original question. If yes, apologies

Comment: @Kaushik Please ignore/forget that. English is my second language, and I tried to say something totally different than you read.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You want to change this line:

```
public void bar() throws MasterException, MinorException
```

to this:

```
public void bar() throws MasterException
```

Everything else should work exactly how you've written it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the MinorException from throws clause of bar().

Answer (score 0):

I would remove MasterException from foo() as you are catching it and as the other answers say, MinorException from bar().

Additionally, in case MasterException or MinorException is a subclass of RuntimeException, you do not need to declare it. See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: I just made up exceptions name off the top of my head, I'm not using these exceptions it was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove  `throws MasterException`  from the declaration of method `foo()`, the reason is clear that the MasterException has been ready catched SO would not get occurred anyway.
2. Remove `, MinorException` from the declaration of method `bar()`.